How to fix the bottom gap issue in Telegram Mini App for iOS
I am developing a Telegram Mini App, but it seems I made a mistake in the configuration or setup.
When using the Telegram mini app on an iPhone, there is a gap at the bottom of the screen.
The following image shows the preview on Telegram for PC, which is correct:

The following second image shows the preview on iOS, where the gap at the bottom appears:

This issue only occurs on iOS. Could you help me resolve this?
It seems to be the same problem as described in How to remove bottom gap in Telegram mini app, and I tried the suggested solution, but it did not fix the issue.
My app has a screen where the content scrolls beyond the device's height.

On PC, VisualViewport Height is 844px, and Telegram WebApp Height is 844px.
On iOS, VisualViewport Height is 732px, and Telegram WebApp Height is 698px.
